# how do i go from an _ast.Dict to an actual dict?

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree

i have an ast object that returns type '_ast.Dict'

how do i convert that into a regular dict?

my failed attempts -

```
type(item.value) -> <type '_ast.Dict'>

eval(item.value) -> *** TypeError: eval: argument 1 must be string or code object

ast.parse(item.value,mode="eval") -> *** TypeError: expected a readable buffer object

dict(item.value) -> *** TypeError: '_ast.astlist' object is not callable

len(item.value) -> *** TypeError: object of type '_ast.Dict' has no len()
```

Comment: did you try to pass it to `dict()`?

Comment: Do you need a real `dict`? Is `_ast.Dict` not a `dict`-like object?

Comment: edited question with results from above suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

There are two decent ways to go about getting a regular Python dictionary from an `_ast.Dict`. Which is better may depend on what the contents of the dictionary are.

If your `ast.Dict` instance contains regular Python objects (like lists and strings), you can directly convert it to a regular `dict` with `dict(zip(d.keys, d.values))`.

However, if your dictionary contains other `ast` nodes rather than the corresponding regular objects (e.g. `ast.Str` for strings and `ast.Num` for numbers), you probably want to recursively evaluate everything. The best way I see to do this is to wrap your dictionary in an `ast.Expression`, then pass it to the built in `compile` function to turn it into a code object. The code object can then be passed to `eval`.

In your example, I suspect that `item` is an `ast.Expression` already, so you can skip the step of packing the `ast.Dict` into an `Expression`. You can get a regular `dict` with:

```
dct = eval(compile(item, "<ast expression>", "eval"))
```

Comment: interesting. this returns None or if i remove the "eval" call i get <type 'tablecode'>

Comment: @MatthewKime: You mean that `dct` is `None` after you do this? That seems strange. Perhaps `item` isn't an expression as I thought. Can you post more about it? If it's some other type, `dct = eval(compile(ast.Expression(item.value), "<ast expression", "eval"))` should work if `item.value` is an `ast.Dict`, regardless of what `item` is itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
my_dict = ast.Dict(keys=('first','second'), values=(1,2))

print type(my_dict)                   #<class '_ast.Dict'>

answer = dict(zip(t.keys,t.values))
print answer                          #{'second': 2, 'first': 1}
```

Comment: Um, the `__dict__` attribute is just how all attributes are stored in objects. Using `my_dict.keys` and `my_dict.values` directly would be more natural.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I agree with you, and edited the answer.